# How to unzip a 7zip archive in Android?

Tags: java, android, archive, 7zip

I have a `7zip` archive which contains some hundred files separated into different directories. The target is to download it from a FTP server and then extract it on the phone.

My problem is that the `7zip` SDK doesn't contain a lot. I am looking for examples, tutorials and snippets regarding the decompression of 7z files.

(Decompression via `Intent` is only a secondary option)

Comment: A list of 7-Zip tutorials is at the bottom of <a href="http://www.7-zip.org/links.html">this page</a>.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the links on the 7zip page are quite old and not usable for me. I forked this question into another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469904/

Comment: You might want to have a look at AndroXplorer v.3. It supports many file formats including 7z.

Comment: Have you tried this solution -> http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_(Programmatically) ?

Answer (score 2):

Go [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/J7Zip/4.43%20Alpha%202/):

LZMA SDK just provides the encoder and decoder for encoding/decoding the raw data, but 7z archive is a complex format for storing multiple files.

Comment: Do you have any demo project

Answer (score 1):

i found this [page](http://jules.dourlens.com/extract-manipulate-7zip-android/) that provides an alternative that works like a charm. You only have to add `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8'`

to your build gradle script and use the feature you desire. For this issue i did the following :

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = am.open("a7ZipedFile.7z");
            File file1 = createFileFromInputStream(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
SevenZFile sevenZFile = null;
        try{
            File f = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "a7ZipedFile.7z");
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while((length=inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
            }

            try {
                sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(f);
                SevenZArchiveEntry entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry();
                while (entry != null) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getName());
                    FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(entry.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    byte[] content = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
                    sevenZFile.read(content, 0, content.length);
                    out.write(content);
                    out.close();
                    entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry();
                }
                sevenZFile.close();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            //Logging exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The only draw back is approximately 200k for the imported library. Other than that it is really easy to use.

Comment: It seems like it also requires NDK.

Comment: @Bugs Happen It does not required NDK

Comment: There's a limitation with apache 7zip and zip that it does not supported encryption